# How do I wrap some text to a span with a class

Tags: jquery, text, replace, element

I want to add a class to all body text that contains a specific text ...

this is the code I tried to use but it hasn't worked

```
$("body").html().replace("by care", "<span class='blue'> by care </span>");
```

Comment: You can try for class .blue : { word-break: break-word; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the actual body html after you've replaced some of the content:

```
var replacedHtml = $("body").html().replace("by care", "<span class='blue'> BY CARE </span>");
$('body').html(replacedHtml);
```

To replace ALL instances, change the replace to:

```
var replacedHtml = $("body").html().replace(/by care/g, "<span class='blue'> BY CARE </span>");
```

The `g` switch stands for global - replace globally.

Comment: thx, i forgot that step ... right now it is only replacing on the first occurence, but its a progress :)

Comment: solved :)

```var replacedHtml = $("body").html().replace(/by care/g, "<span class='blue'> by care </span>");

$('body').html(replacedHtml);```

Comment: I just updated my answer to show replacing globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and `.split()`.

Here is a working example:

[image: LIVE DEMO Snapshot]

[Here is the link to the live bin.](http://jsbin.com/fusakut/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
var toSelect = 'by care';
var selection = $(".container :contains('"+toSelect+"')");

$.each(selection, function(i, s){
    var sp = $(s).text().split('by care');
    $(s).html(sp[0]+"<span class='blue'>"+toSelect+"</span>"+sp[1]);
})
```